# Android: Передача данных из AsyncTask в Активити

Tags: android, java

Есть проблема, когда из образа класса беру значение переменной в нём null (или стандартное значение).
Класс:

```
  public class ShowBar extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
    {
       ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
       public String info;
       private  boolean today = true;
       private Context context_dialog;
       ...

  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
   long result = 0;
   Elements links;

   final String URL = "http://ya.ru";

   if (today)
       {

           Document doc = null;
           try {
               doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
               links = doc.select("table[class=translation]");
               info =  links.outerHtml();

           }catch (Exception e){

           }
       }

   return result;
```

}

Вызов из активити:

```
 bar = new ShowBar(this,true);
 bar.execute();
 info2 = bar.info;
```

info2 равно null.
Как это можно исправить?
Нужно передать это значение в активити. 
З.Ы. Внутри класса ShowBar у переменной нужное значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Задача попала в очередь на выполнение и вернула управление вам. Но, при этом, еще не выполнилась.
2. Судя по коду, вы не можете быть уверены в том, что полю bar.info присваивается какое-либо значение, т.к. в блоке try/catch могло произойти исключение, которое вы просто игнорируете.

Comment: Спасибо.
Как мне справится с 1 пунктом?
Ума не прилажу.

Comment: Например можно так:

Описать интерфейс (назовем его OnCompleteListener), с методом OnComplete(String info)

Имплементим этот интерфейс для класса откуда вызываемся

При этом у конструктора ShowBar будет не Context, а OnCompleteListener (то есть у вас будет поле listener

Переопределяем метод onPostExecute у ShowBar, в котором вызываем listener.onComplete(this.info)

Ну это как один из возможныз вариантов

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд несколько странное использование AsyncTask. Сам смысл использования AsyncTask в том, что он служит своего рода адаптером между обработкой загружаемых данных и вызвавшим его объектом. Мне кажется, что реализация OnCompleteListener тут лишняя.
Можно просто возвращать info, перегрузить onPostExecute и выполнить всю работу в нем.

Comment: Честно, я написал такой вариант потому что у меня есть отдельно описанные AsyncTask'и используемые в нескольких местах. Ни в коем случае не претендовал на истину в последней инстанции :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте info2 =bar.execute.get .

Comment: Пожалуйста, давайте более развернутые ответы